# How to return multiple values from XML element in SQL?

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I need to pull information from the "Name" element from an XML column in SQL. An example of the XML is below:

```
<ArrayOfTarget xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TriTech.InformRMS.Domain.Core.ComplexTypes">
  <Target>
    <AgencyId>ca2fa1dd-2cd4-c219-bea5-08d6fbe6d96c</AgencyId>
    <AgencyName i:nil="true" />
    <Id>19bc33e1-a788-cd99-3dab-08d92aa7d030</Id>
    <Name>Case Number WB21-006637</Name>
    <Type>Case Management</Type>
  </Target>
  <Target>
    <AgencyId>ca2fa1dd-2cd4-c219-bea5-08d6fbe6d96c</AgencyId>
    <AgencyName i:nil="true" />
    <Id>cb4d829b-c31a-cadb-5c9e-08d934b7404d</Id>
    <Name>Incident Supplement Number WB21-006637.006</Name>
    <Type>Data Entry</Type>
  </Target>
  <Target>
    <AgencyId>ca2fa1dd-2cd4-c219-bea5-08d6fbe6d96c</AgencyId>
    <AgencyName i:nil="true" />
    <Id>6b23195c-4650-c0c9-925d-08d71a88f611</Id>
    <Name i:nil="true" />
    <Type>Template</Type>
  </Target>
  <Target>
    <AgencyId>ca2fa1dd-2cd4-c219-bea5-08d6fbe6d96c</AgencyId>
    <AgencyName i:nil="true" />
    <Id>b465517c-5926-c6b3-1cc6-08d6fbe6da27</Id>
    <Name>Default Workflow</Name>
    <Type>Workflow</Type>
  </Target>
  <Target>
    <AgencyId i:nil="true" />
    <AgencyName i:nil="true" />
    <Id i:nil="true" />
    <Name>Complete</Name>
    <Type>Workflow Step</Type>
  </Target>
</ArrayOfTarget>
```

I have this SQL Query which works for returning five of the "Name" elements:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS i,
                    'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TriTech.InformRMS.Domain.Core.ComplexTypes' AS s)
SELECT TOP 100
TargetData_Xml,
Description,
TargetData_Xml.value('(/s:ArrayOfTarget/s:Target/s:Name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Context1,
TargetData_Xml.value('(/s:ArrayOfTarget/s:Target/s:Name)[2]', 'varchar(100)') as Context2,
TargetData_Xml.value('(/s:ArrayOfTarget/s:Target/s:Name)[3]', 'varchar(100)') as Context3,
TargetData_Xml.value('(/s:ArrayOfTarget/s:Target/s:Name)[4]', 'varchar(100)') as Context4,
TargetData_Xml.value('(/s:ArrayOfTarget/s:Target/s:Name)[5]', 'varchar(100)') as Context5
FROM
[InformRMSAudit].[dbo].[AuditEntities]
WHERE
CaseNumber = 'RP21-010802'
ORDER BY
Date desc
```

That would be sufficient if every record had only five "Name" elements in the XML, but the number of "Name" elements varies from record to record.

How could I change my query to handle the variation from record to record?

Comment: Do you *need* the values in a separate column, rather than a row? If so, the only method would be with dynamic SQL. A result set *must* be well defined, so if you need a dynamic number of columns you need a dynamic statement. Personally I suggest against this if you have no idea what you're doing with such syntax.

Comment: Since I have no experience using dynamic SQL I will heed your advice. If the values were in rows instead of separate columns how would you suggest doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

As @Larnu pointed out, it is much better to shred the XML as rows.

If needed it is very easy to filter out names with NULL values.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, TargetData_Xml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (TargetData_Xml) VALUES
(N'<ArrayOfTarget xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TriTech.InformRMS.Domain.Core.ComplexTypes">
    <Target>
        <AgencyId>ca2fa1dd-2cd4-c219-bea5-08d6fbe6d96c</AgencyId>
        <AgencyName i:nil="true"/>
        <Id>19bc33e1-a788-cd99-3dab-08d92aa7d030</Id>
        <Name>Case Number WB21-006637</Name>
        <Type>Case Management</Type>
    </Target>
    <Target>
        <AgencyId>ca2fa1dd-2cd4-c219-bea5-08d6fbe6d96c</AgencyId>
        <AgencyName i:nil="true"/>
        <Id>cb4d829b-c31a-cadb-5c9e-08d934b7404d</Id>
        <Name>Incident Supplement Number WB21-006637.006</Name>
        <Type>Data Entry</Type>
    </Target>
    <Target>
        <AgencyId>ca2fa1dd-2cd4-c219-bea5-08d6fbe6d96c</AgencyId>
        <AgencyName i:nil="true"/>
        <Id>6b23195c-4650-c0c9-925d-08d71a88f611</Id>
        <Name i:nil="true"/>
        <Type>Template</Type>
    </Target>
    <Target>
        <AgencyId>ca2fa1dd-2cd4-c219-bea5-08d6fbe6d96c</AgencyId>
        <AgencyName i:nil="true"/>
        <Id>b465517c-5926-c6b3-1cc6-08d6fbe6da27</Id>
        <Name>Default Workflow</Name>
        <Type>Workflow</Type>
    </Target>
    <Target>
        <AgencyId i:nil="true"/>
        <AgencyName i:nil="true"/>
        <Id i:nil="true"/>
        <Name>Complete</Name>
        <Type>Workflow Step</Type>
    </Target>
</ArrayOfTarget>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TriTech.InformRMS.Domain.Core.ComplexTypes')
SELECT ID
    , c.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Name]
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY TargetData_Xml.nodes('/ArrayOfTarget/Target') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------------------------------------------+
| ID |                    Name                    |
+----+--------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Case Number WB21-006637                    |
|  1 | Incident Supplement Number WB21-006637.006 |
|  1 | NULL                                       |
|  1 | Default Workflow                           |
|  1 | Complete                                   |
+----+--------------------------------------------+
```